# Oracle SQL - Join 2 table columns in 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 SQL's and the result come fine. They are no relation between those 2 queries but I want to see all the rows in single column.

e.g.

```
Select col1,col2,sum(col3) as col3 from table a
select col4,col5 from table b
```

I would like the result to be

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
```

If there is no equivalent row for either table a or table b replace with zeroes.

Could some one help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there are the same number of rows in each table?

Comment: Hi - There might be or might not be same number of rows....if they are no rows replace them with zeroes

Comment: If you want to merge columns from 2 queries, you will have to create join. But as you said, there is no relation then how do you create a join? It would be helpful if you can provide sample of your actual query/data

Comment: first of all your first sql query is **WRONG**, you need to use **GROUP BY**

Comment: Sorry we have group by - Select proj_name,col1,col2,sum(col3) as col3 from table a group by proj_name
select col4,col5 from table b . group by proj_name

Answer (score 0):

Since, you didn't provided any information like table structure or data inside each tables. You can `cross join` both tables.

```
select t.col1,t.col2,t.col3,t1.col1,t1.col2 from tab1 t,tab2 t1;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf89aa/3)**

Answer (score 0):

In both select statements add column based on `rownum` or `row_number()` and then `full join` results using this column:

```
select nvl(col1, 0) col1, nvl(col2, 0) col2, nvl(col3, 0) col3, 
       nvl(col4, 0) col4, nvl(col5, 0) col5
  from 
    (select rownum rn, col1, col2, col3 from (
      select col1, col2, sum(col3) col3 from tableA group by col1, col2)) a
  full join (select rownum rn, col4, col5 from tableB) b using (rn)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8d6c/1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `UNION` could be a pragmatic solution since the 2 queries are not related. They are just 2 data sets that should be retrieved in one statement:

```
Select col1,col2,sum(col3) as col3 from table a
UNION
select col4,col5, to_number(null) col6  from table b
```

Be aware of col6 in the example. `SQL` insists on retrieving an *equal set of columns* in a `UNION` statement. It is a good practice to retrieve columns with exactly the same `datatype`. Since the sum(col3) will yield a `number datatype` column, col6 should too.

The outcome of col4 and col5 will be shown in col1 and col2.